# How to get Value from Execute command as output parameter in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the result from the catch block from store procedure and pass it as output parameter. So I could use result in select statement with a field value. For now it is executing correctly, but the select statement returns me NULL Value.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_calc] @mathexpr NVarchar(20), @returnValue decimal(9,2) out
as
declare @query varchar(800)
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT @returnValue=CAST(@mathexpr as decimal(9,2))
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @query='SELECT CAST('+@mathexpr+' as decimal(9,2))'
    EXECUTE(@query)
END CATCH

declare @result decimal(9,2)
exec sp_calc @mathexpr='1.600*2.5478/1.2',@returnValue=@result out
select @result as result
```

Thank's for help.

Comment: You're not assigning your dynamic execution into anything, you're just selecting it. At least having a temp table + insert into it should allow you to capture the result and then assign it to your variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use the `INSERT..EXECUTE` structure to execute your dynamic SQL and store the results in a variable that the code outside of the dynamic sql can access.

Answer (score 0):

Here is full code that do my job. I made little changes like using float instead of decimal, and NVarchar instead of Varchar. Global temp table is created out of the store procedure, so it is can be used out of the sp. Hope this will help and others.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##NSesion') IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE ##NSesion
  END 

create table ##NSesion (ID int identity,F1 float null)
exec sp_calc @appSesion=##NSesion, @mathexpr='1*2/3'
select F1 as r from ##NSesion
drop table ##NSesion

create procedure [dbo].[sp_calc] @APPSesion NVarchar(10), @mathexpr NVarchar(20) 
as 
declare @query NVarchar(800) 
declare @RV float 
BEGIN TRY 
  SELECT @RV=CAST(@mathexpr as float) 
  if (@RV<>0) or (not @RV is null) 
  SET @query='insert into '+@APPSesion+' (F1) values ('+@RV+') ' 
  EXECUTE(@query) 
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH 
  SET @query='insert into '+@APPSesion+' (F1) values (CAST('+@mathexpr+' as float)) ' 
  EXECUTE(@query) 
END CATCH
```